# Что значит рекомендация CA2122 Security::Permissions LinkDemand при анализе C++clr кода?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, visual-studio-2017, clr

Я провел анализ своего кода и получил рекомендацию от анализатора (см. ниже). Не понимаю, что он хотел этим сказать? (VS-2017)

Код:

```
try
{
    SD::Imaging::BitmapData ^bmd0 = nullptr;
    SD::Imaging::BitmapData ^bmd1 = nullptr;
    dataComparable *dc = nullptr;

    try
    {
        bmd0 = bmp0->LockBits(
            SD::Rectangle(Point(0, 0), bmp0->Size),
            SD::Imaging::ImageLockMode::ReadOnly,
            SD::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format32bppArgb
        );
        bmd1 = bmp0->LockBits(
            SD::Rectangle(Point(0, 0), bmp1->Size),
            SD::Imaging::ImageLockMode::ReadOnly,
            SD::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format32bppArgb
        );

        dc = new dataComparable();
        dc->d1.d = xUtils::IntPtrToPointer<PBYTE>::get(bmd0->Scan0);
        dc->d2.d = xUtils::IntPtrToPointer<PBYTE>::get(bmd1->Scan0);
        dc->d1.sz = static_cast<size_t>(bmd0->Stride * bmp0->Height);
        dc->d2.sz = static_cast<size_t>(bmd1->Stride * bmp1->Height);

        return funcComparable(dc);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dc)
            delete dc;
        if (bmd0 != nullptr)
            bmp0->UnlockBits(bmd0);
        if (bmd1 != nullptr)
            bmp1->UnlockBits(bmd1);
    }
}
catch (Exception ^)
{
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Рекомендации анализатора:

> csemudev.h(276): warning CA2122: Microsoft.Security :
> 'EmuDev::CompareBitmap(Bitmap^, Bitmap^)' выполняет вызов в
> 'Bitmap::UnlockBits(BitmapData^)', для которого задана проверка
> LinkDemand. Выполняя этот вызов, 'Bitmap::UnlockBits(BitmapData^)'
> косвенно предоставляется пользовательскому коду.
>
> Рассмотрите следующий стек вызовов, который может раскрыть способ обхода защиты
> безопасности:
> csemudev.h(276): warning CA2122:
> ->'EmuDev::CompareBitmap(Bitmap^, Bitmap^)'
>
> csemudev.h(276): warning CA2122:
> ->'EmuDev::CompareBitmap(Bitmap^, Bitmap^)'

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @Kromster, Проблему я вижу в рекомендациях анализера, я их не понимаю. Если вы сможете объяснить тип рекомендации - буду признателен. `Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.` - копи-паста из правил не вносит ясности в ваше замечание.

Comment: Так-то речь, возможно, идет об атрибутах безопасности https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.securityaction?view=netframework-4.7.2 . Правда, я не нашел, что бы на данном методе стоял атрибут. Это стандартный класс .NET или какая-то левая либа?

Comment: Это смешанная библиотека (clr), сам класс где этот метод NET ref, атрибутов нет никаких. Мне вот тоже смысл рекомендации не удалось понять.

Comment: Изучил ссылку, может в связи с употреблением LockBits и предположительно необходимостью использовать в коде UnlockBits на усмотрение автора, необходимо указать именно эти атрибуты с точки зрения vs?

Comment: Вопрос и ответ подправил, флаг отозвал. Проверьте плиз, можно ли еще уточнить вопрос (например указав инфо об анализаторе и т.п.)?

Comment: @Kromster,  Спасибо, версию уточню позже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В двух словах, сам [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/ms182303(v=vs.80)) описывает это коротко и не очень понятно. Смысл сводиться к тому, что в стандартных библиотеках некоторые вызовы уже защищены атрибутами `System::Security::Permissions::*` и, при обращении к ним, требуют аналогичного установленного атрибута доверия со стороны кода вызывающего эти функции/методы.

`LinkDemand`- требование ссылки - это информация о безопасности доступа к коду (CAS), которая гарантирует, что код имеет достаточные права для выполнения.
Предупреждение как таковое может не относится к логике вашего кода, если вы уверены что этот код не будет выполнен снаружи. Защитив "ненадежный код" атрибутами безопасности, можно быть уверенным что код не сможет выполнить "джит" и не сможет быть выполнен извне.

**Зачем так сделано**

Помеченный атрибутами безопасности код будет использовать повышение привилегии стека вызовов. По умолчанию .NET предполагает, что ваш код полностью доверенный, пока не будет установлен соответствующий атрибут. Этот механизм обеспечивает выполнение кода с более низкими учетными записями и приоритетами (зависит от настроек атрибутов).

Проверка `Требование ссылки` выполняется во время компиляции и проверяет разрешения вызывающего. Возможная утечка безопасности может произойти из-за того, что ваша ссылка на  метод/функцию/класс может быть вызвана другим кодом позднее. Этот код не получит такую ​​же проверку разрешения, потому что в ссылке отсутствует атрибут безопасности. Чтобы избежать этой проблемы, рекомендуют использовать опцию атрибутов безопасности`FullTrust`.

Путей решения я нашел три:

1. Запретить вывод предупреждения использовав атрибут `SupressMessage`, так себе решение..

> `[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CA2122:DoNotIndirectlyExposeMethodsWithLinkDemands")]`

2. Использовать глобальные атрибуты на всю сборку снимающие проверки `System::Security::Permissions` в той или иной степени: [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/security-transparent-code) [blog MSDN SecurityTransparent](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2009/11/03/transparency-101-basic-transparency-rules/)

> ```
> [assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level2)]
> если сборка помечена как:  
> [assembly: SecurityTransparent]
> [assembly: SecurityCritical]
> [SecurityCritical(SecurityCriticalScope.Everything)] Class/Method
> ```

3. Использовать необходимые атрибуты на вашем методе, который вызывает метод/функцию помеченную атрибутами `System::Security::Permissions`, общий работающий атрибут касающийся `Unmanaged` кода у меня выглядит так:

   ```
   [System::Security::Permissions::SecurityPermission(
       System::Security::Permissions::SecurityAction::LinkDemand,
       Flags = System::Security::Permissions::SecurityPermissionFlag::UnmanagedCode,
       Unrestricted = false
   )]
   ```

так-же, из общих соображений я перенес тело функции в `internal:`, возможно это и не обязательно, но без этого подавить ошибку не удавалось.